# libarchive equivalent of fgetws()

Tags: widestring, libarchive

I'd like to modify a program, which currently simply loops over its input with `fgetws()`, to be able to transparently process *compressed* input-files -- using [libarchive](https://www.libarchive.org/).

Unfortunately, I cannot find a libarchive equivalent for the `fgetws()` -- one can read blocks of data, but how to find *strings* in them? I loath implementing such a thing myself -- a string could well span multiple input blocks! Worse, an individual wide character (including the wide EOL-character -- `L'\n'`) could span multiple input blocks.

Perhaps, this is implemented already? Any other suggestions?